# Can someone explain the solution (provided) of this conical pendulum work problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, work

In the image, it looks like the tangential direction is always 45 degrees away from the string, not 90 degrees. Is it not the circular path that the solution is talking about?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 45 degrees with respect to a vertical plane containing the pendulum ball's instantaneous direction of motion but you need to consider the angle of the tension force with respect to the ball's motion. That plane is spanned by the pendulum's length and the instantaneous direction of motion of the ball and you can see that these are orthogonal, 90 degrees, therefore no work is done.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I understand now :) I would have upvoted your answer if I had 15 reputation!